# React-Native 0.63.4 not receiving responses to requests

Tags: react-native, flipper

I have a RN 0.63.4 app setup. Everything was working fine earlier, but now none of my requests are resolving. I have Flipper set up and can see my request going out and the response coming in, but in my app it never resolves, so I get stuck on the request indefinitely. I have no idea what is going on, and it is getting really frustrating. Is there something else I need to set up to work properly with Flipper, or is that just something completely separate. I have tried using both apisauce and a normal fetch request (both GET and POST). I see everything in flipper, but nothing on my actual app or in the console logs in flipper after I make the call. Any help is greatly appreciated. (All requests are resolving to 200 in the Network section of flipper, too)

Answer (score 0):

Check if your domain has ipv6 configured. I also had same error, and setting up ipv6 resolved the issue for me.